# How to pass individual records from a list to a Dialog in MVC and allow user to accept or reject the record passed using buttons inside the dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am struggling to figure this out, I have a MVC app that does an upload of a CSV file to a few, I then pass the list of data to a stored procedure which performs validation on the records from the CSV file, I now need to write the validated response from the list to a dialog box individually so user can accept or reject the record, then on click of accept go to the next record and so on, if the reject button is clicked them just simply close the page (this I got working with a simple close function in Jquery dialog). I am struggling pass data to the dialog as click accept then move to next record and display in dialog.

Please see my code below to see how far I have come.

I have 2 view, one is Index which just uploads CSV and display list of data , then there is a button on the View called Validate Claims, which opens the dialog box, this is where my question lies.

Here is my Index View:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />


@using CSVSupplierClaims.Models
@model List<CSVSupplierClaims.Models.SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList>



<button type="submit" id="validateClaims" value="Validate Claims" size="5" data-url="@Url.Action("ValidateClaims", "Home", new { area = "supplierClaimUplaod" })">Validate Claims</button>

<input type="submit" value="Import Claims to CRM" size="5" />

<div id="dialog" title="Claims Validation">
    Accept or Reject The following record
    <p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>ST Key</td>
                <td>Supplier Claim</td>
                <td>Orig Inv</td>
                <td>Error</td>
                <td>System Cost</td>
            </tr>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var claim in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@claim.ST_Key</td>
                        <td>@claim.SupplierClaim</td>
                        <td>@claim.OrigInv</td>
                        <td>@claim.Error</td>
                        <td>@claim.SystemCost</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </table>
    </p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });

        $("#validateClaims").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open"),
                       $("#dialog").dialog({
                           resizable: true,
                           height: 300,
                           width: 500,
                           modal: true,
                           closeOnEscape: true,
                           buttons: {
                               "Accept": function () {
                                   **//This is where my question lies**

                                   $(this).dialog("close");
                                   $(this).empty();
                               },
                               "Reject": function () {
                                   alert('Validation cancelled..');
                                   $(this).dialog("close");
                               }
                           }
                       });
        });
    });

</script>



<div class="CSSTableGenerator">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>No.</td>
            <td>Action</td>
            <td>LineNo</td>
            <td>TotalClaim</td>
            <td>ClaimReference</td>
            <td>Currency</td>
        </tr>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var c in Model)
            {
                counter++;
                <tr>
                    <td>@counter</td>
                    <td>@c.Action</td>
                    <td>@c.LineNo</td>
                    <td>@c.TotalClaim</td>
                    <td>@c.ClaimReference</td>
                    <td>@c.Currency</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

    </table>
</div>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table style="margin-top:150px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="file"> Filename</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
using CsvHelper;
using CSVSupplierClaims.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Crm;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace CSVSupplierClaims.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string path = null;

            List<SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList> supplierClaimsData = new List<SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList>();

            try
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "upload\\" + fileName;
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(path));

                    var supplierList = csv.GetRecords<SupplierClaimsUpload>();

                    foreach (var supplier in supplierList)
                    {
                        SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList supplierUploadDisplay = new SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList();

                        supplierUploadDisplay.Action = supplier.Action;
                        supplierUploadDisplay.LineNo = supplier.LineNo;
                        supplierUploadDisplay.TotalClaim = supplier.TotalClaim;
                        supplierUploadDisplay.ClaimReference = supplier.ClaimReference;
                        supplierUploadDisplay.Currency = supplier.Currency;

                        supplierClaimsData.Add(supplierUploadDisplay);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewData["error"] = "Uplaod failed";
            }
            TempData["claimsResponse"] = supplierClaimsData;

            return View(supplierClaimsData);
        }

        public ActionResult ValidateClaims()
        {
            List<SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList> supplierClaimsData = (List<SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList>)TempData["claimsResponse"];

            //= new List<SupplierClaimsUploadDisplayList>();
            Supplier_Claim_Upload_Results supplierClaimUplaod = new Supplier_Claim_Upload_Results();

            var sqlConnection = "data source=WMVSQL02;initial catalog=Embrace;integrated security=True;";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var claim in supplierClaimsData)
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                        SqlDataReader reader;
                        cmd.CommandText = "CRM.Supplier_Claim_Upload";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Invoice", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = claim.LineNo;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = claim.TotalClaim;
                        cmd.Connection = conn;

                        conn.Open();
                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            claim.ST_Key = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ST_Key"));

                            if (claim.SupplierClaim != null)
                            {
                                claim.SupplierClaim = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Supplier_Claim"));
                            }
                            else if (claim.SupplierClaim == null && claim.OrigInv == null && claim.SystemCost == null)
                            {
                                if (claim.Error != null)
                                {
                                    claim.Error = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Error"));
                                }
                                else if (claim.Error == null)
                                {
                                    claim.SupplierClaim = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Supplier_Claim"));
                                }
                            }
                            if (claim.OrigInv != null)
                            {
                                claim.OrigInv = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Orig_Inv"));
                            }
                            else if (claim.OrigInv == null)
                            {
                                if (claim.Error != null)
                                {
                                    claim.Error = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Error"));
                                }
                                else if (claim.Error == null)
                                {
                                    claim.OrigInv = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Orig_Inv"));
                                }
                            }
                            if (claim.SystemCost != null)
                            {
                                claim.SystemCost = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("System_Cost"));
                            }
                            else if (claim.SystemCost == null)
                            {
                                if (claim.Error != null)
                                {
                                    claim.Error = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Error"));
                                }
                                else if (claim.Error == null)
                                {
                                    claim.SystemCost = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("System_Cost"));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        conn.Close();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = ex.Message + ex.InnerException;
                }
            }
            return View(supplierClaimsData);
        }
    }
}
```

Just to reiterate my issue, I need the validate claims button click event to pass my list as individual records to the dialog, once user clicks accept code should add that record to a new list and then dialog must display the next record. I am comfortable with server side code, I am just struggling with the client side Jquery to read my list and pass records to dialog. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Inject the response from an ajax call. The contents of the dialog should be dynamic i.e the result of an ajax call. you would then inject it with something like $("#dialog .content").html("the response, of ajax ie the partial view.")

Comment: Seabizkit could you perhaps show me an example or point me to a link where the concept is explained.

Comment: Look for examples(google) of mvc partial views and calling them via jquery ajax.